# LyX: pdflatex does not put both header and footer text with page number

Tags: header-footer, lyx, margins, koma-script

Using TeXLive/2023 (updated today) on Slackware linux and LyX-2.3.6.1. The document class is KOMA-Script Report.

I used to have the pdflatex output display text in the page headers and footers with the page number in the footer center. Both header and footer were separated from the body text with a solid horizontal line.

Somehow, something broke and now there's only the header text with no separating line. The page layout style makes no difference.

A minimal example showing this problem is:

```
#LyX 2.3 created this file. For more info see http://www.lyx.org/
\lyxformat 544
\begin_document
\begin_header
\save_transient_properties true
\origin unavailable
\textclass scrreprt
\begin_preamble
\date{}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{mathpazo,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx,relsize}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}
\usepackage{chngcntr,xurl}
\counterwithout{figure}{section}
\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.8}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\lehead{Biological Evaluation}
\rohead{Biological Evaluation}
\refoot{Applied Ecosystem Services, LLC}
\lofoot{Applied Ecosystem Services, LLC}
%\automark*{sections}
\end_preamble
\use_default_options false
\maintain_unincluded_children false
\language english
\language_package default
\inputencoding utf8
\fontencoding global
\font_roman "palatino" "default"
\font_sans "avant" "default"
\font_typewriter "libertine-mono" "default"
\font_math "auto" "auto"
\font_default_family default
\use_non_tex_fonts false
\font_sc false
\font_osf false
\font_sf_scale 100 100
\font_tt_scale 100 100
\use_microtype false
\use_dash_ligatures true
\graphics default
\default_output_format default
\output_sync 0
\bibtex_command biber
\index_command default
\paperfontsize 11
\spacing single
\use_hyperref false
\papersize letterpaper
\use_geometry true
\use_package amsmath 1
\use_package amssymb 1
\use_package cancel 1
\use_package esint 0
\use_package mathdots 0
\use_package mathtools 1
\use_package mhchem 1
\use_package stackrel 1
\use_package stmaryrd 1
\use_package undertilde 1
\cite_engine biblatex-natbib
\cite_engine_type authoryear
\biblio_style plain
\biblatex_bibstyle authoryear
\biblatex_citestyle authoryear
\use_bibtopic false
\use_indices false
\paperorientation portrait
\suppress_date false
\justification true
\use_refstyle 0
\use_minted 0
\index Index
\shortcut idx
\color #008000
\end_index
\leftmargin 0.75in
\topmargin 0.5in
\rightmargin 0.5in
\bottommargin 0.5in
\secnumdepth 5
\tocdepth 5
\paragraph_separation indent
\paragraph_indentation default
\is_math_indent 0
\math_numbering_side default
\quotes_style english
\dynamic_quotes 0
\papercolumns 1
\papersides 2
\paperpagestyle default
\tracking_changes false
\output_changes false
\html_math_output 0
\html_css_as_file 0
\html_be_strict false
\end_header

\begin_body

\begin_layout Title
A Long Title:
\begin_inset Newline newline
\end_inset

Which Has Two lines
\end_layout

\begin_layout Subtitle
And a multiline
\begin_inset Newline newline
\end_inset

sub-title
\end_layout

\begin_layout Date
\begin_inset ERT
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
today
\end_layout

\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Chapter
General information
\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
\begin_inset ERT
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
lipsum[1-30]
\end_layout

\end_inset


\end_layout

\end_body
\end_document
```

Comment: The MWE is in the code block. No, the problem is the non-chapter heading page. I've been using KOMA-Script classes for more than 20 years so I understand how headers and footers are presented. My question is why they stopped working. The MWE I posted shows the entire preamble and if you compile it with pdflatex you'll see that there are no footers.

Comment: Ok, after taking a look I don't know what happened but I know how to put the header and/or footer lines. See my answer.

Answer (score 3):

[image: Mwe]

<kbd>Document</kbd>  → <kbd>Settings...</kbd> → <kbd>Document Class</kbd>   → `Custom:`   → type `headsepline, footsepline`

(And increase at least the bottom margin to 1 cm or so, to see the footer.)

Comment: Yes, the problem was too little space on the page bottom. I increased the space to 1in and the footer text and page number appear. The issue is resolved. Thanks all of you for commenting.